# I can't create table in H2 database

Tags: java, jdbc, junit, h2

I am trying to create a relational table in an H2 database and then query based on it.
However, I am getting this error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "accomodation_fare_relations" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT accomodation.type,room_fare.value,room_fare.season FROM accomodation_fare_relations JOIN accomodation ON accomodation.id = accomodation_fare_relations.id_accomodation JOIN room_fare ON room_fare.id = accomodation_fare_relations.id_room_fare [42102-200]
```

I have no idea how to solve this, I managed to create the tables, that have the many-to-many relations, but I do not know how to solve this.

I leave here my code for anyone who could help me:

```
public class MainTest {
Connection conn;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    //create h2 DB
    try {
         Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE", "sa", "");
    Statement statement1 = conn.createStatement();
    Statement statement2 = conn.createStatement();
    Statement statement3 = conn.createStatement();


statement1.execute("CREATE TABLE accomodation\n" +
            "(\n" +
            "    id integer NOT NULL,\n" +
            "    type character varying(32) NOT NULL,\n" +
            "    bed_type character varying(32) NOT NULL,\n" +
            "    max_guests integer NOT NULL,\n" +
            "    description character varying(512) NOT NULL,\n" +
            "    CONSTRAINT accomodation_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)\n" +
            ");");


    statement2.execute("CREATE TABLE room_fare\n" +
            "(\n" +
            "    id integer NOT NULL,\n" +
            "    value double precision,\n" +
            "    season character varying(32) ,\n" +
            "    CONSTRAINT room_fare_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)\n" +
            ");");


    statement3.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE accomodation_fare_relations (\n" +
            "  id integer,\n" +
            "  id_accomodation integer NOT NULL,\n" +
            "  id_room_fare integer NOT NULL,\n" +
            "  PRIMARY KEY (id),\n" +
            "  FOREIGN KEY (id_accomodation) REFERENCES accomodation(id)\n" +
            "                        ON DELETE CASCADE,\n" +
            "  FOREIGN KEY (id_room_fare) REFERENCES room_fare(id)\n" +
            "                        ON DELETE CASCADE\n" +
            ");");


    insertDataIntoAccommodation(conn);
    insertDataIntoRoomFare(conn);
    insertDataIntoAccommodationFareRelation(conn);
    conn.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}


private void insertDataIntoAccommodationFareRelation(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO accomodation_fare_relations VALUES (?,?,?)");

insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 1, 1, 1);
insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 2, 1, 5);
insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 3, 1, 9);
insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 4, 1, 13);

insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 5, 2, 2);
insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 6, 2, 6);
insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 7, 2, 10);
insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 8, 2, 14);

insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 9, 3, 3);
insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 10, 3, 7);
insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 11, 3, 11);
insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 12, 3, 15);

insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 13, 4, 4);
insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 14, 4, 8);
insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 15, 4, 12);
insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 16, 4, 16);

insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 17, 5, 2);
insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 18, 5, 6);
insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 19, 5, 10);
insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 20, 5, 14);

insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 21, 6, 2);
insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 22, 6, 6);
insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 23, 6, 10);
insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(ps, 24, 6, 14);

}

private void insertRowIntoAccommodationFareRelation(PreparedStatement ps, int id, int id_accommodation, int id_room_fare) throws SQLException {
ps.setInt(1, id);
ps.setInt(2, id_accommodation);
ps.setInt(3, id_room_fare);

ps.executeUpdate();
}


@Test
public void testSelect() throws SQLException {
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT " +
        "accomodation.type," +
        "room_fare.value," +
        "room_fare.season " +
        "FROM accomodation_fare_relations " +
        "JOIN accomodation ON accomodation.id = accomodation_fare_relations.id_accomodation " +
        "JOIN room_fare ON room_fare.id = accomodation_fare_relations.id_room_fare");
ResultSet resultSet =  ps.executeQuery();

while (resultSet.next()) {
    System.out.println(resultSet.getString("type"));
    System.out.println(resultSet.getDouble("value"));
    System.out.println(resultSet.getString("season"));
    System.out.println("-------------------------");
    System.out.println("-------------------------");
}
}
}
```

Comment: What was the value of the boolean returned to you when executing that  CREATE TABLE? What exceptions were thrown?

Comment: @BasilBourque  It throws exceptions only when I try to query

Comment: Query for a list of tables to verify the specific table did indeed get created.

Comment: @BasilBourque the table was not created, hence the exception

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @BasilBourque I'm curious why you ask about the boolean return value of executing the create table. It doesn't seem relevant here, as it only signifies whether the first result is a result set (true) or - possibly - an update count (false).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I provided it  as the first answer

Comment: Don't post answers with information that belongs in your question. Please [edit] your question. Answers are only for answers to your question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am done editing it

Comment: Is there a reason you use `statement.executeUpdate()` for the third table and `.execute()` for the other two?  Also, when you write "I managed to create the tables", how sure are you of this?  Your `setUp()` method catches any `Exception`s, writes their stacktrace to standard error and then your code keeps running.

Comment: @LukeWoodward, i quried the first two tables, that's why I know they were created

Comment: @LukeWoodward for some reason the third table it is not created

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem with the code you've posted.  I ran it and it created the three tables. All I can suppose (and this is a complete guess) is that you wrote a version of the code that created just the first two tables, ran that, the first two tables got created, you then added the code to create the third table to your program but the code to create tables won't create the third table because the first table already exists and you get an exception because of that.

Comment: @LukeWoodward so if I rewrite it from scratch, and run it only once it might work?

Comment: @LukeWoodward I will try it and see what happens

Comment: @LukeWoodward still the same problem

Comment: Would deleting the database files be an option for you?  This would wipe all data in them, including any other tables you haven't mentioned.  The database files should be in your home folder (`C:\Users\Username` on Windows).  If you can delete them, try doing this and then running your program again.

Comment: @LukeWoodward it worked, all tests have passed, I still get some exceptions saying that one of the tables already exists, but the tests pass and seem to display the correct output. Thank you so much